# Cardinality of subfields of real numbers

Tags: field-theory, real-numbers

I know that the set of real numbers is a field, and so is its subset, the set of rational numbers.

Are there any more fields which are subsets of the set of real numbers? If not, is there a proof?

Answer (score 2):

The transcendence degree of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$: there is a set $A$ of $2^{\aleph_0}$ algebraically independent transcendentals in $\Bbb R$.
If $B\subseteq A$ we get a field $\Bbb Q(B)$ by adjoining the elements of $B$ to $\Bbb Q$. Different $B$ give different $\Bbb Q(B)$. This way we get $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ subfields of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Infinitely many. For instance, $\mathbf Q(\sqrt p)$ where $p$ is any prime number. If $p\ne p'$, $\;\mathbf Q(\sqrt p)\ne\mathbf Q(\sqrt p')$.

Comment: Could it be proved whether the number of fields is aleph-one or aleph-zero?

Comment: @RamRachum Alephs may not be the best cardinals to think about here. The *Beth numbers* $\beth_n$ defined by $\beth_0:=\aleph_0,\,\beth_{n+1}=2^{\beth_n}$ imply there are at least $\beth_1$ but at most $\beth_2$ subfields. I suspect we can prove one of these is the exact cardinality, but ZFC doesn't prove which alephs they are.

Comment: Algebraic extensions are $\aleph_0$, but it's more complex for transcendental extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Examples are the set of rational numbers and the set of algebraic numbers. Another example is $\ \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})=${$a+b\sqrt{2}\mid a,b\in \mathbb Q$}

Answer (score 0):

Let $k\subset\Bbb{R}$ be any subfield and $r\in\Bbb{R}$ any element. Then $k(r)$ is again a subfield.

Starting from $\Bbb{Q}\subset\Bbb{R}$ you can keep adjoining elements to get (uncountably!) infinitely many subfields of $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: My best guess is this doesn't tell us the exact cardinality of the set of fields on $\Bbb R$. You've shown there are at least $\beth_1$ of them, but $\Bbb R$ has $\beth_2$ subsets. Ideally we'd want a proof the cardinality is $\beth_1$, or a proof it's $\beth_2$.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for the response. The question does not ask for that cardinality, and a proof seems beyond the level of the question, so I won't bother.

Comment: We could debate whether the current title asks how many fields there are or how many elements they each have, but an earlier title definitely asked how many fields exist.